# Process scope object in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have an element directive that looks like this:

```
app.directive("ngArticle", [function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "/partials/article.html",
    scope: { article: "=article" }
  }
}]);
```

And used like this:

```
<ng-article data-article="{{object goes here}}"></ng-article>
```

This works absolutely fine. But now, I want to access part of the object passed through the directive and process it before it renders out. For example, if the object inside `data-article` looks like this:

```
{
  category: "Going Out",
  id: "1234"
}
```

In the directive, I want to access the `category` value, replace whitespace with hyphens and change it all to lowercase. Is this possible within the directive?

I don't want to do this in a controller because the directive is used across multiple controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your object before it rendered using link function within directive:

```
app.directive("ngArticle", [function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "/partials/article.html",
    scope: { article: "=article" },
    link(scope, element, attrs) {
      ...
    }
  }
}]);
```

Also, scope is not interpolated before the linking function so you can `watch` your article object:

```
scope.$watch('article', function() {
    // do your transformations here
}
```

Remember to clean up your watchers before your directive destroy, this can prevent memory leaks

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    // clean up watchers here
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried `console.log(scope)` within the link function and that shows be the full scope including the new addition to the scope `article`. But when I try `console.log(scope.article)` it returns undefined...

Comment: If I use a timeout, it shows the full article object. How do I wait for the scope to be fully applied within the directive before running the link function?

Comment: @Coop I've updated an answer, using $timeout is an option but you also can you $watch